# Why does my URL redirect not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I download CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and I followed the [tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) on CodeIgniter 2.1.0.

The problem is when I try to submit a form in this URL:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/create
```

the page is redirected to this URL:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/create
```

I tired many ways to change the route.php but it doesn't work. How can I fix this??

**route.php**

```
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

This is the code for the form page:

```
public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->set_news();
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
}
```

I notice that when the form page when the page is loaded, below code segment will executed, however, the else segment never got changes to execute.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
```

This is the form page, nothing special, just call the create function shown above.
**create.php**

```
<h2>Create a news item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/create') ?>

<label for="title">Title</label> 
<input type="input" name="title" /><br />

<label for="text">Text</label>
<textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" /> 

</form>
```

This is the HTML for the form page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Create a news item - CodeIgniter 2 Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CodeIgniter 2 tutorial</h1><h2>Create a news item</h2>

<form action="localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="title">Title</label> 
<input type="input" name="title" /><br />

<label for="text">Text</label>
<textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" /> 

</form><strong>&copy;2012</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I press the `create new item` button, the URL changed to

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/create
```

and page shows `404 Pages Not Found`

Comment: What is the `action` for your form? I know you're using `form_open()`, but just humor me and check the HTML output.

Comment: the form is to insert a new news to database, which includes a news title and a news body.

Comment: All forms have an `action` attribute, I'm asking what that value is in your HTML output.

Comment: OK, the form page will be generated by function create() shows above. If the form validator runs with no error, it will redirect the page to  success.php, which only tells you have already submit a form; else it will reload the for page.

Comment: Give us the HTML from your browser while you're viewing the form please

Comment: @zqkun - you should have edited your question (there is an edit link) to include this information, not posted it as an answer. I have done this for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, it caused by the improper base url setting.

Before my base url was: `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/CodeIgniter';`

Now I changed it to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';
```

and it works fine now.

Thanks for whoever tried to help:)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, may be it can helps you:

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Set this in your config.php file, you will never be worried about `$config['base_url']`. Because it will set `http` or `https` port, `domain`, `port number` (ex. 8080, 8880 etc.) and `codeigniter root folder`. Also it can be reused in future in your any codeigniter project. :)

you can also check [this article](http://www.palgenep-center.com/dynamic-base-url-code-igniter.html)